# Recursively Load Shapefiles from Directory Structure Based on Name Pattern using PyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-python-console

I have a directory `repository` which contains multiple subfolders, which themselves contain multiple sub(sub)folders. Inside the subfolders or sub(sub)folders there are shapefiles. I am looking for a way to load all shapefiles`.shp` stored in any subfolder or sub(sub)folder that match a given name pattern.

Here is one example of shapefile:

```
"\Users\myname\project\repository\subfolder1\country1_borders.shp"
```

```
"\Users\myname\project\repository\subfolder1\subsubfolder2\country1_capital.shp"
```

In the example above the naming pattern is `country1_*.shp`. Using the python console in QGIS how can I load all shapefiles starting with this pattern?

```
import os

from qgis.core import (
    QgsVectorLayer
)

path_to_shp = "/Users/myname/project/repository/*/*/country1_*.shp"

layer = iface.addVectorLayer(Select_folder, "country1_*", "ogr")

if not layer.isValid():
    print("Layer failed to load!")
else:
    QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)
``
```

Comment: Just as a hint: the above code is flawed and will partly crash QGIS, see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/441047/loading-shapefiles-with-addmaplayer-in-pyqgis-does-not-display-them-until-rest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are fine with a **GUI solution**, just use the plugin [Load Them All](https://github.com/gacarrillor/loadthemall), which allows you to set your filter and load all shapefiles recursively.

[image]

If you still need to code it, there are several ways of doing that. For instance:

### Using [`os.walk()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.walk)

```py
import fnmatch
for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk("/docs/geodata/"):
    for name in files:
        if fnmatch.fnmatch(name, "country1_*.shp"):
            print(os.path.join(dirpath, name))
```

### Using [`glob.glob()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/glob.html#glob.glob)

```py
import glob
for filename in glob.glob("/docs/geodata/**/country1_*.shp", recursive=True):
    print(filename)
```

That will give you complete paths for the shapefiles that match your condition. Now you'll need to load them to QGIS as you already know:

```py
iface.addVectorLayer(filename, os.path.basename(filename), "ogr")
```

Comment: thank you for your fast answer. I will use the glob.glob() solution. I followed your instructions but got the following message: "TypeError: glob() got an unexpected keyword argument 'recursive'". I found this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56103938/glob-got-an-unexpected-keyword-argument-recursive QGIS on my macbook is version 2.18.15

Comment: Wow, your QGIS is really old (I guess you have your own good reasons for that). So, the recursive parameter was added in Python 3.5. Because of your old Python, I'd suggest you to go for option 1 (`os.walk`), perhaps you need to call `import os` first. That's the option I was using in LoadThemAll, even for QGIS v2.x.

Comment: I am updating my QGIS. Version 3.20 now. Thank you again for your kind help.