# Loading Shapefiles with addMapLayer() in PyQGIS does not display them until restart of QGIS

Tags: pyqgis, shapefile, qgis-3

Hm, I just encountered a very strange phenomenon with this function I just wrote:

```
    def loadLayersFromFolder(self, sourceFolder):
    """
    Load all Shpfiles as Layers from a given path (i. e. folder).
    """

    layerList = []
    # Get the filenames using glob
    # see https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/408958/recursively-load-shapefiles-from-directory-structure-based-on-name-pattern-using
    QgsMessageLog.logMessage("loadLayersFromFolder mit sourceFolder= " + sourceFolder, level=Qgis.Info)
    for filename in glob.glob(sourceFolder + "\*.shp", recursive=True):
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage(filename, level=Qgis.Info)
        layer = iface.addVectorLayer(filename, os.path.basename(filename)[:-4], "ogr")
        layerList.append(layer)
        if not layer.isValid():
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Layer " + filename + " failed to load!", level=Qgis.Error)
            #QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Layer " + filename + " failed to load!", level=Qgis.Warning)
        else:
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, True)
            #QgsProject.instance().reloadAllLayers()
      
    return layerList
```

After running the function the layers are shown in the layer tree, attribute table etc. everything is working fine. However the layers are not shown on the map until I restart QGIS completely. It even goes as far as that no other layer in my existing project is working anymore (when toggeling them on/off) and when I zoom into the map it blurrs.
As you can see I even tried the `True` flag in `addMapLayer()` and `reloadAllLayers()` but to no avail.

Here's what its look like when I zoom:
[image]

I also tried with a new project, same result (ok, the map canvas is obviously all white in this case).

Is this an error or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [QgisInterface.addVectorLayer()](https://api.qgis.org/api/classQgisInterface.html#a787122c2d5d3e9b50c2bd9d6d7c0c4e4) method, as well as returning a `QgsVectorLayer` object, also adds the layer to the project. So you are doing this twice using two different methods. I suggest changing:

```py
layer = iface.addVectorLayer(filename, os.path.basename(filename)[:-4], "ogr")
```

To:

```py
layer = QgsVectorLayer(filename, os.path.basename(filename)[:-4], "ogr")
```

Testing with the following simplified snippet worked fine for me:

```py
import glob

def loadLayersFromFolder(sourceFolder):
    layerList = []
    for filename in glob.glob(sourceFolder + "/*.shp", recursive=True):
        # Construct the layer object
        layer = QgsVectorLayer(filename, os.path.basename(filename)[:-4], "ogr")
        layerList.append(layer)
        if not layer.isValid():
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Layer " + filename + " failed to load!", level=Qgis.Error)
        else:
            # Now add it to the project
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer, True)
    return layerList
    
lyrs = loadLayersFromFolder('/path/to/some/folder/containing/shapefiles')
print(lyrs)
```

P.s. On Ubuntu, I also had to change the backslash to a forward slash here: `"/*.shp"`

Comment: Thanks so much Ben, works like a charm :-) I'm going to leave a note in the question I based my code on.